# error: variable ‘use_dilation’ set but not used in building intel caffe

Tags: caffe

I am trying to build intel caffe.
I use g++ version 5.5.0.

I have error at

```
src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:91:8: error: variable ‘use_dilation’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
    bool use_dilation = false;
    ^
    src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Layer > caffe::GetConvolutionLayer(const caffe::LayerParameter&) [with Dtype = double]’:
    src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:163:1: required from here
    src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:91:8: error: variable ‘use_dilation’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
    cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
    Makefile:810: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o' failed
    make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o] Error 1
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

What could be wrong?

I tried to add
use_dilation = false; after the initialization.
But still have error.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Value is assigned but obviously not used, the compiler is trying to give you the heads up. I am not sure why it is generating an error but not a warning... include the code please

Comment: @UlugToprak here is the code `https://github.com/intel/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning itself is just minor. As Ulug Toprak pointed on, there is simply an unused variable. But you get an error because of this:

```
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

In Makefile:422 there is this line:

```
CXX_HARDENING_FLAGS += -fPIC -fno-operator-names -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wall -Werror
```

which causes warnings to be treated as errors. Just remove `-Werror` flag.